# JavaScript - Closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm reading the explanation of closures on Mozilla developer site and am struggling a bit. Please have a look at the following code from Mozilla website. I kind of understand how it works but I'd think that the code below my comments should also work. Why does it not work if one click on 18 and 20?

```
/* mozilla dev code */
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
      document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
/* end of mozilla dev example */
/* my code starts */
/* see - no inner function below */

function makeS(size) {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px'
}
/* Let's see if that works */

var size18 = makeS(18);
document.getElementById('size-18').onclick = size18;



/* What about that? */

document.getElementById('size-20').onclick = makeS(20);
```

Why

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/qqoooW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`makeS(18)` *immediately invokes the function* and changes the size. What you assign to the `onclick` event in that case is actually `undefined`, since that's what the function returns when invoked, as it has no explicit return.

```js
function makeS(size) {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px'
}

console.log("font size before calling makeS:", document.body.style.fontSize); //it's actually an empty string, hence why it doesn't show up in the output

var size18 = makeS(18);

console.log("font size after calling makeS:", document.body.style.fontSize);

console.log("what is size18?", typeof size18);
```

By contrast, `makeSizer(18)` will *create a new function* that when called, will change the size.

```js
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
      document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}

console.log("font size before calling makeSizer:", document.body.style.fontSize); //it's actually an empty string, hence why it doesn't show up in the output

var size18Function = makeSizer(18);

console.log("font size after calling makeSizer:", document.body.style.fontSize); //it's still an empty string

console.log("what is size18Function?", typeof size18Function);

//let's call it now
size18Function();

console.log("font size after calling size18Function:", document.body.style.fontSize); //it's now changed
```

Answer (score 4):

A closure is fact of 'remembering' variables of the scope chain by the function when it is defined. Since function argument is just a local variable during execution, this:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
      document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}
```

is an equivalent to:

```
function makeSizer() {
    var size = 1; // or some other value
    return function() {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}
```

In the above case, the anonymous function, which is the return value, will 'remember' value of `size` variable and use it each time it is called.

MakeSizer should be treated as a 'factory' function that provides different values for local variable `size`.

You cannot acheive this kind of 'remembering' without using a function definition statement inside of 'factory' function.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of 18 your calling makeS. It does not return anything to size18,siz18 would be undefined here,if you want to make it work through clousre change makeS(),to return a method as similar to makeSizer

check this snippet

```js
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;


function makeS(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  }
}

/* Let's see if that works */

var size18 = makeS(18);
document.getElementById('size-18').onclick = size18;


/* What about that? */

document.getElementById('size-20').onclick = makeS(20);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>How closures work</h1>
<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>

<div>
  <a href="#" id="size-18">18</a>
  <a href="#" id="size-20">20</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A closure refers to the concept of a function retaining access to variables in the lexical scope that it was declared within, even as it is passed, and called in different locations and scopes throughout a program.

**Huh?**

What does this mean then? Consider the below piece of code

```
function functionFactory() {
    var x = 1;
    return function () {
        return ++x;
    };
}

var first  = functionFactory();
var second = functionFactory();

console.log(first()); // outputs 1
console.log(first()); // outputs 2
console.log(first()); // outputs 3

console.log(second()); // outputs 1
```

Each time `functionFactory` is called, it declares a private variable `x`, and then returns an anonymous function that mutates that variable. We can see in the output that each subsequent call of that returned function, `first`, returns a different value.

When we call `second` though, it returns 1. Why? Because it was created by a separate invokation of `functionFactory`, and so it has its own reference to its own closure over `x`.

**Why do I care?**

Because this is super-useful. In programming languages (like javascript, but other functional languages too) which treat functions as first-class variables, we can use closures for encapsulation of private variables.

**So to your actual question...**

The reason why your code is not working, is because `onclick` expects you to assign a function to it - instead you are assigning the output of your `makeS` function, which is `void`. `makeSizer` is returning a function, that establishes a closure over whatever number value is passed into it as a parameter, and is then assigned to the `onclick` variable of each element.

Hope this makes things clearer for you.